# Внедрение зависимости в Linq2Db при доступе к контексту

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, linq2sql

В официальной документации по Linq2Db приведен такой код, демонстрирующий то, как нужно обращаться к базе данных:

```
using LinqToDB;
using LinqToDB.Common;

public static List<Product> All()
{
  using (var db = new DbNorthwind())
  {
    var query = from p in db.Product
                where p.ProductID > 25
                orderby p.Name descending
                select p;
    return query.ToList();
  }
}
```

Как видим, в этом куске кода присутствует new DbNorthwind(), что вроде бы является нехорошей зависимостью, которую необходимо устранять.

Подозреваю, что люди, писавшие сей код являются грамотными программистами и знают, что делают.

В связи с чем вопрос: является ли new DbNorthwind() зависимостью, которую надо устранять путем внедрения в конструктор, или такая зависимость является допустимой?

Comment: вы задаете широкий вопрос и думаете, что получите единтвенно верный ответ на это, который сможете раз и навсегда запомнить и использовать в своей практике. Ах, если бы всё было бы так просто. На самом деле подходы есть разные, и они сильно зависят от проекта и его структуры. Например, если вы пишете репозиторий, будете ли создавать контекст в каждом его методе? Если нет, то как вы будете освобождать контекст? А если вы работаете над контроллером asp.net? Или над настольным приложением? В каждом случае могут быть разные сценарии, каждый раз придется думать головой.

Comment: Да, у меня получается репозиторий. Контекст создается в каждом методе. После того, как реализовал DI, задумался: using (var db = new DbNorthwind() больше нет - контекст не освобождается значит? Следовательно надо было оставить все как в примере?

Comment: Ну или ваш репозиторий должен реализовывать `IDisposable` - зависит от того, как вы репозиторий использовать собрались.